# Does Unity's "Compression quality" affect ETC2 compression?

Tags: unity, textures, performance

In Unity I am using "Advanced" texture options on Android with ETC2 8-bit compression. There is an option for "Compression quality" as described here: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextureImporter.html

It seems like the compression quality can impact runtime performance according to that documentation -- but as far as I can tell, ETC2 8-bit doesn't normally have different performance characteristics based on how the texture was compressed... Does the Compression Quality setting actually make a difference with ETC2 8-bit compression on Android?